# how to copy files and directory from source to destination using python

Tags: python, shutil, os.walk

i want a python script that do these three tasks:

1. check if the path contains word file  copied to specific destination
2. check if the path contains pdf files  copied to specific destination
3. check if the path contains directory  and copy the hole folder  to
   specific destination.

for this reason i am using the **os.walk()** to list the dirs and files of the path
and i am using **shutil library** to copy files and dirs.

## code

```
import os
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
import shutil
from os import path
import datetime

def main():
    src = "C:/Users/LT GM/Desktop/Python_files/"


    dst2 = "C:/Users/LT GM/Desktop/"
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
        for name in files:
            print("files: ",os.path.join(root,name))
        for name in dirs:
            copieddst = copy_tree(src,dst2)
            print("directory: ",os.path.join(root,name))
            print(" coppied directory :{0}".format(copieddst) )
    # make a duplicate of an existing file
        if path.exists(src):
    # get the path to the file in the current directory
            print("****")
            src = path.realpath("pandas.pdf")

    #seperate the path from the filter
        head, tail = path.split(src)
        print("path:" +head)
        print("file:" +tail)    
        dst =str(datetime.date.today()) + tail  
    # nowuse the shell to make a copy of the file
        shutil.copy(src, dst)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

the problem is that i can copy the files or the content of the directory. not the hole directory and how  to check if its **pdf** or **doc** files?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy directory rather than file, then use [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree). In usage it is similiar to `shutil.copy2`, that is:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree('mydir', 'mydircopy')
```

Note that by default `dirs_exist_ok` is `False` meaning that destination should not exist, when `shutil.copytree` is launched.

Comment: You can copy to already existing destination if you do `shutil.copytree('mydir', 'mydircopy', dir_exists_ok=True)` however keep in mind that: *New in version 3.8: The dirs_exist_ok parameter.* which means you can use it only in `Python 3.8` or newer